# What is the datatype of pointer in c?

Tags: c, pointers

are pointers of integer or unsigned datatype?

Comment: Integer and unsigned are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: In fact, only integral types can be unsigned. Neither pointer types nor floating-point types can be unsigned.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. They're pointers, whose size is system-dependent and whose only compatible type is `void*`.

Comment: Another compatible type is `char*`.

Comment: There has to be a compatible integer type, although which one is implementation-defined, such that you can convert a data pointer to it and back again and have the same pointer.

Comment: MSalters : `char *` as a generic pointer is deprecated usage isn't it?

Comment: David : I think it's `int_ptr` which should be available on all platforms abstracting away the platform specific details.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim C99 requires `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`

Comment: @Secure POSIX, on the other hand, requires them to be so. (We can haz `dlsym()`, can't we.)

Comment: Pointer types other than `void*` are not *compatible* with `void*`. The existence of an implicit conversion is not the same thing as type compatibility, which is rather narrowly defined.

Comment: @H2CO3: `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`, are optional. A conforming implementation with no integer types big enough to old a converted `void*` value without loss of information will not define them. (I know of no such implementations, but they're possible.)

Answer (score 11):

Pointers are of pointer type.  If you're asking about how pointer values are represented in memory, that really depends on the platform.  They may be simple integral values (as in a flat memory model), or they may be structured values like a page number and an offset (for a segmented model), or they may be something else entirely.

Answer (score 4):

In C, pointer can access the variables of any data types. The pointer should be declared with the data type of the variable the pointer will be pointing. To print the address of the pointer in hexadecimal format use `%p` and to print the address in other forms use `%u`.If the pointer is going to be used to display value of pointing variable, use `*pointer_name` and just for address use `pointer_name`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe pointers itself are data types. This belief of mine came from the book written by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie 2nd edition from Introduction part stating that -

**BCPL and B are "typeless" languages. By contrast, C provides a variety of
data types. The fundamental types are characters, and integers and floating point numbers of several sizes. In addition, there is a hierarchy of derived data types created with pointers, arrays, structures, and unions.**

Please discuss or share your views.

Reference - c programming language by dennis ritchie

Answer (score -3):

int *p;

data type of *p is  pointer.
And it points to integer type variable.
It stores address in hexadecimal format.

Comment: *"It stores address in hexadecimal format."* I don't think that's true.

Answer (score -4):

**Pointers to any datatype either it may be of char/int/float/double/... are unsigned integers only.**

**Reason**: Since a pointer stores the address, which is a location in computer memory, it's always positive,can't be negative.

Comment: No, pointers are not "unsigned integers". Pointers are pointers.

Comment: what do u mean by pointers are pointers, could you explain a little more on that statement? what i mean was an address cant be negative, so it must be an unsigned integer.

Answer (score -4):

What is the data type of pointer in C? is the unique question.

One should not deviate from the question to give any kind of explanation on pointers as the answwer to the question?

Answer.

1. What is the data type name of a set of intergers in C? The name is int , which is the name of the set comprising of all the permissible integers. Hence we declare int x; where x can assume any value from the set.
2. Similarly , What is name of the set of all the permissible addresses or pointers? .The set name can only be the character  '*' as I fathom, though no explanation is seen anywhere in C language narratives.

Hence we declare the pointer variable as *x; where * is the data type name. Otherwise why should a pointer data type is thought about and brought under the user defined data type.
Since there are all the RAM cells, the '*' data type forms a subset of permissible and accebile memory cells. Hence this is a data type name of a set of pointers.

The int is the modifier as in signed char c;  where signed is the modifier in C.Hence we may have  int *x; to mean that data in the location is an integer which is a  necessary information for the compiler.

C speaks about pointer data type as the user data type. Perhaps it is wrong to consider the pointer data type as the user data type since the user has no control over the set of pointers in the set, going by the basic concept of int is the set name, float is the set name, char is the set name of haracters, double is the set name of floats of high precision numbers, colour is the data type name in  enum colour = { blue, red, yellow).