# Understanding void* against intptr_t and uintptr_t

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, integer

This is the code I'm testing:

```
int value = 0;
void* addyvoid = static_cast<void*>(&value); // C++-style cast.
```

it works perfectly, but I could use `uintptr_t` / `intptr_t`. But they are not good for holding pointers as people said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492910/7242258) because they are too big. So, is this true? If yes, however, for holding pointers using `void*` would be better, but will there be a loss of data?

Comment: you can't use `uintptr_t` / `intptr_t` unless you change it to `reinterpret_cast`, and no, it will keep required data

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The purpose of `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` is that in some applications, you actually do need to do some sort of numeric computation on pointer values, perhaps by flipping individual bits, perhaps by [XORing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list) them, etc. In those cases, when you need to work with the *numeric* value of a pointer, `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are integer types that (if they exist) are guaranteed to be large enough to hold any pointer. This is not true of, say, `int`, since `int`'s size relative to pointer sizes isn't specified.

Because it's fundamentally unsafe to do these conversions, C++ requires that you use `reinterpret_cast` to convert to and from `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` and pointer types.

If all that you're doing is storing "a pointer to something," and provided that pointer isn't a function pointer or a member function pointer, you can just cast it to `void*`. That cast is guaranteed to work and the conversion from `void*` back to the original type only requires a `static_cast` and is guaranteed to be safe.

The size of `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` isn't a good reason to avoid them. They're just for different applications. If you need to do numeric computations on pointers, use those types. Otherwise, if you just need to store "a pointer to something," use a `void*`.